# Cannot install RabbitVCS and SVN on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, svn, rabbitvcs

I just upgraded my pc to ubuntu 16.04 and tried to make it ready for development but it has many issues. One unsolved issue is I tried every possible way but I cant installed RabbitVCS in pc:

```
    sudo apt-get install subversion
    sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs*
    sudo ln -s "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0" "/usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0"
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rabbitvcs/ppa
    sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-nautilus3
```

I have taken updates after trying everything I can find on google. Nothing worked and I repeatedly got following

[image]
Please suggest if there is any solution except returning back to 14.04.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Old ticket but I've just had this problem and found a temporary if not ideal solution by using the trusty release file instead.

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

Then edit the contents in text file rabbitvcs-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.
Edit the line

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
```

to

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
```

Then

> sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get install --packages--

Answer (score 3):

I will also add an answer to this old question because the proposed change to "trusty" version didn't work for me.

In fact, this was not needed at all since rabbitvcs is already part of the official repo for Ubuntu 16.04. Just remove the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rabbitvcs-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list and do `apt update` followed by `apt install rabbitvcs-nautilus rabbitvcs-cli`

Answer (score 0):

Please use do below commands in terminal to install rabbitvcs in Ubuntu 18.04 or later version and finally logout & login to get effect in file manager

```
sudo apt-get install python-nautilus python-configobj python-gtk2 python-glade2 python-svn python-dbus python-dulwich subversion meld
```

```
sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-nautilus thunar-vcs-plugin rabbitvcs-gedit rabbitvcs-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried other solutions but did not work for me. Perform the following steps to install RabbitVCS.

```
sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-nautilus

mkdir -p ~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions

cp /usr/share/nautilus-python/extensions/RabbitVCS.py \
~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions
```

Restart Nautilus

```
nautilus -q
```